# where to put CSS/JS files for FOSbundle Template overriding?

Tags: php, symfony

I am very beginner in  symfony and using symfony 2.8.
I have use FOS bundle for login and registration.

I want to use bootstrap template for login and registration.

1) I have put `layout.html.twig` file in `app/Resources/FOSUserBundle/views` directory

2) I have also put

```
{% block fos_user_content %}{% endblock fos_user_content %}
```

block in my `layout.html.twig` file

3) and put my CSS/JS files in following directory

`web/bundles/FOSUserBundle/public/css`

`web/bundles/FOSUserBundle/public/js`

4) and use above css & js file in my `layout.html.twig` file as below

```
{% block stylesheets %}
 <link href="{{ asset('FOSUserBundle/public/js/jquery-2.2.3.min.js') }}" rel="stylesheet" />

 {% endblock %}
 {% block javascripts %}
   <script src="{{ asset('FOSUserBundle/public/js/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>
 {% endblock %}
```

but i am not able to see bootstrap layout in registration form.

Comment: what version of symfony are you running? Why don't you use assetic (or other tools) to handle your css or js? Moreover I suppose that path to your css/js isn't a good one: try to insert `bundles` before each path, because the default directory is `web` not `web/bundles`

Answer (score 0):

1. override FOSUserBundle layout by adding the file layout.html.twig in app/Resources/FOSUserBundle/views
2. Extends this layout from your base layout. Eg.

   `{% extends 'myapp_base.html.twig' %}`

   `{% block content %}
      {% block fos_user_content %}{% endblock %}
   {% endblock %}`
3. In your myapp_base.html.twig add bootstrap files

   `{% block stylesheets %}
       <link href="{{ asset('assets/css/bootstrap.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" />
   {% endblock %}`

   `{% block content %}{% endblock %}`

   `{% block javascripts %}
       <script src="{{ asset('assets/js/bootstrap.js') }}"></script>
   {% endblock %}`

Don't put bootstrap files in web/bundles folder as those files are copied from bundles public folder (`assets:install` command).

Instead you can put theme in `/web/assets/js` and `/web/assets/css` folder (for a manually installation).